# Why does Array(repeating: Dog(), count: 7) make an array of 7 elements pointing to the same Dog instance?

Tags: arrays, swift

Assuming `Dog` is a class

```
let arr = Array(repeating: Dog(), count: 7)
```

Why do all the elements in the array point to the same dog instance ?
Now, I know to run a normal for loop and create 7 instances like

```
var arr = [Dog]()
for i in 1...7 {
   arr[i] = Dog()
}
```

But that's not the point. I wanna understand the `init(repeating:count:)` function at a deeper level. Please share any insights you have !

Comment: https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-improve-init-repeating-count/6495

Comment: This depends on whether `Dog` is a struct or a class. In case of a struct you get multiple instances.

Comment: @vadian I think it's better to think of it (and explain it) in terms of "copies". Instances of classes get copied by duplicating references that point to the same objects. Instances of structs get copied by duplicating the entire instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as documented - repeats **single value**. In your case a value is pointer to once created instance of class `Dog`.

> ```
> /// Creates a new collection containing the specified number of a single,
> /// repeated value.
> ///
> /// Here's an example of creating an array initialized with five strings
> /// containing the letter *Z*.
> ///
> ///     let fiveZs = Array(repeating: "Z", count: 5)
> ///     print(fiveZs)
> ///     // Prints "["Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z"]"
> ///
> /// - Parameters:
> ///   - repeatedValue: The element to repeat.
> ///   - count: The number of times to repeat the value passed in the
> ///     `repeating` parameter. `count` must be zero or greater.
> @inlinable public init(repeating repeatedValue: Element, count: Int)
> ```

Comment: Could you also add a link to the source?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica, which source? `Array` interface declaration? It is standard Swift Collection module. Or I misunderstood something?

Comment: Oh I thought you quoted that from the github repo. I see now that it's a generated interface (since there's no opening `{`)

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing special, it's just how values of class type are copied. Instances of classes get copied by duplicating references that point to the same objects. Instances of structs get copied by duplicating the entire instances.

To achieve what you want to do, you need to create a separate instances for each position in the array. You can do that using a closure provided to `map`:

```
(1...7).map { _ in Dog() }
```

Answer (score 0):

If Dog is a struct - the two instances are in fact different:

```
struct  Dog  {
    var hungry = true
}

var arr = Array(repeating: Dog(), count: 2) // two hungry dogs
print(arr[0].hungry) // true
print(arr[1].hungry) // true
arr[1].hungry = false // feed second dog
print(arr[0].hungry) // true
print(arr[1].hungry) // false
```

Else if Dog is a class - the two instances are the same (both reference the same object):

```
class Dog  {
    var hungry = true
}

var arr = Array(repeating: Dog(), count: 2) // two hungry dogs
print(arr[0].hungry) // true
print(arr[1].hungry) // true
arr[1].hungry = false // feed second dog
print(arr[0].hungry) // false
print(arr[1].hungry) // false
```